# Postgresql: partition by number of rows after the current one

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions

I need to calculate correlation for each say 3 consecutive rows.

For example, assume there is a table with the following data.

```
create table a (
    asset_id int,
    time int not null,
    value decimal not null
);
insert into a values
(1,1,30),(1,2,45),(1,3,30),(1,4,30),(1,5,30),
(2,1,30),(2,2,40),(2,3,30),(2,4,25),(2,5,25);


# select row_number() over() as r, a.asset_id, b.asset_id, a.time, a.value, b.value
from a join a b on a.time=b.time and a.asset_id<b.asset_id;

 r | asset_id | asset_id | time | value | value
---+----------+----------+------+-------+-------
 1 |        1 |        2 |    1 |    30 |    30
 2 |        1 |        2 |    2 |    45 |    40
 3 |        1 |        2 |    3 |    30 |    30
 4 |        1 |        2 |    4 |    30 |    25
 5 |        1 |        2 |    5 |    30 |    25
(5 rows)
```

The correlation of entire series can be calculated like this

```
# select a.asset_id, b.asset_id as asset2_id, corr(a.value, b.value)
from a join a b on a.time=b.time and a.asset_id<b.asset_id group by a.asset_id, b.asset_id;

 asset_id | asset2_id |        corr
----------+-----------+--------------------
        1 |         2 | 0.9128709291752769
(1 row)
```

But I would like it calculated for each 3 consecutive rows, i.e. for rows 1-3, 2-4, 3-5.
Is it possible achieve that?

Comment: What do you believe the answers should be for that?

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
select a.asset_id, b.asset_id, 
    count(*) over w, 
    corr(a.value, b.value) over w
from a join a b on a.time=b.time and a.asset_id<b.asset_id 
window w as (
    partition by a.asset_id, b.asset_id
    order by a.time 
    rows between current row and 2 following
)
```

But it does generate values when you are too close to the end of a partition to be able to have 2 following rows, so with the `count` you can filter those ones out.

So that is how you do it in SQL.  But from a statistics perspective, this seems like malpractice.  That is a topic for a different forum though.

Comment: Can you please expand at least a bit on the malpractice of this approach?